# “Will have to” and “be going to have to”

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference in nuance?

I think you’re going to have to sell your stuff. 
= I think you will have to sell your stuff.

If I think that something is a plan, I have to say “be going to have to”?

Answer (score 0):

> I *am going to have* to leave. *( = the speaker's firm and , perhaps,
> immediate intention );*
>
> I *will have to* leave. *( = decision made at the moment of speaking
> );*

However, both could be *interchangeable* depending on your approach to the language, and on a point of view.

To me, most American speakers would  use the former, whereas the British would the latter. But it's just ***another nuance of the language.***

Also, some people may refer to its usage as whether *informal or formal* seeing that both of the sentences share the same tense, intention, and meaning.

Here are some graphs generated by ngrams:

*BrE:* [Graph 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20have%20to%2Cam%20going%20to%20have%20to&year_start=1800&corpus=29&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20have%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20going%20to%20have%20to%3B%2Cc0)

*AmE:* [Graph 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20have%20to%2Cam%20going%20to%20have%20to&year_start=1800&corpus=28&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20have%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20going%20to%20have%20to%3B%2Cc0)

My personal preference is using *"will have to"* as it's more prominent in writing.